# Metrics for determining what precisely constitutes a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907594/actual-memory-impact-of-adding-an-item-to-a-collection), but there was a duplicate close vote indicating that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617193/does-appending-removing-entries-to-a-java-list-reallocate-memory) is a duplicate.

To me, they read differently, but I don't know for sure that they're different enough to defend my question as 'not a duplicate'.

From my point of view, my question is about *how much* memory is allocated, while the other is more concerned with *when and by what means* memory is allocated. I guess they're both about memory consumption to some degree.

Is there a metric for determining this in cases like these, or does it just come down to waiting to see if other people agree/disagree?

I just want to take the right action and <strike>delete</strike> close my question if it is, in fact, a duplicate.

Comment: Metrics could be incredibly difficult. For example one question could contain the other question and more, or they could have some major parts in common but both also be somewhat different. My rule of thumb: If the answers of one question also answer the other question they are very likely duplicates.

Comment: "I just want to take the right action and delete my question if it is, in fact, a duplicate." As long as you asked a quality question, there's no need to delete it. Duplicates aren't necessarily bad; they help people using different search terms find the same answer.

Comment: @Trilarion In this case, the accepted answer of the question I supposedly duplicated does not answer the question I asked. However, the other answer to that question does answer mine.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I was under the impression that duplicate questions were strictly a bad thing. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @nukeforum That the answer which answers your question is not the accepted one has no bearing *whatsoever* on whether your question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Louis Trilarion's comment seemed to indicate that duplicates are generally identified if the answers of one answer the other. In this case, the question my question is accused of being a duplicate of has exactly two answers. Neither of the answers is remotely similar. They answer two separate things.

Comment: @nukeforum Don't confuse Trilarion's "rule of thumb" with some sort of "SO rule".

Comment: @Louis Ok, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Another thing: If you think your question is really different you may want to edit it to make it even more different, explain why it is different and emphasize the differences. This may make it a non-duplicate. Or you say that the differences are actually so small, it's not worth it. Then you just happily let it stay as duplicate for others and use the solution from any answer of any of the duplicates that solves your problem.

Comment: [ode to dupes... (from the _asker_ perspective:)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773) "Just think of it: someone invested their effort, did some research and let you know that they believe your question has an answer elsewhere.

First thing to do when this happens..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:  I'm a gold-tag holder in Java.  This means I have binding close and reopen vote privileges with questions tagged as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

That said, I'm reading this, and I'm leaning more towards that this is a duplicate, because:

- Both questions are asking about the memory impacts of adding to a data structure
- Both questions' answers contain details about what happens when a fairly large object is added to a data structure (and no, the accepted answer isn't the only answer here)

For balance, compare the unaccepted, unupvoted answer on the suggested duplicate...

> Adding an element to a list does not copy the object that was added to the list. Indeed, no Java statements cause an additional copy of an object to be visible to your program (you have to explicitly use a copy constructor or a clone method to do that). This is because Java objects are never accessed directly, but are always accessed through a reference. Adding an object to a collection really means adding a new reference to the object to the collection.

...to the upvoted answer on your question:

> You have 2MB because you just add a reference to the object and do not create a copy of the object.

These answers are *effectively* saying the same thing; **you're adding a reference and not a copy.**

In all actuality though, your question has the better answer, including an example of how to test this.  For completeness, another answer would ideally explain what happens with a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), since that too is a `Collection`.

So, I'm tempted to say that these questions are duplicates of one another, but since yours has a better answer, I'm considering closing the other question as a duplicate.

Comment: Before you do, can you look a little closer at the other question and make absolutely sure that it is a duplicate? It seems to me the question there is about whether there is a specific type of memory action taken during an add/remove operation. It seems to me that it isn't about whether data is copied at all.

Comment: @nukeforum:  Since my vote is binding, I tend to measure twice and shoot once.  I will probably look at this again when I have some more time, but you bring up a good point.  This is also why gold-badge holders can unilaterally reopen a question closed as a dupe, just in case one of us got it wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time.